# Software to list all IPs on my local network

Tags: windows, networking, network-administration

My local network is assigned IPs using DHCP, meaning that I don't always know which PC has which IP.

Typically, I'd find which PC name was assigned which IP by going to my router's admin web interface.

I'm looking for Windows software (GUI or even a script - powershell or cmd or Perl) that would list all known IPs assigned on my local network and PC names for them.

Freeware preferred. Windows 10 (or 8) compatibility required.

Comment: Why dont you connect to the computers using their hostname ? Besides that: which size network are we talking about ? 5 ? 100 ? Thousands ?

Comment: @Marged - I'm far from expert on Windows, but don't you need to run DNS to connect by hostname? This is home network, between 3 and 8 PCs behind a router.

Comment: DHCP can Register hostnames, many routers support this. Assign a PC a namename and check if you can ping it.

Answer (score 4):

1) There are lots of things that do this.  But over the years,  I have settled on a Nmap as the gold standard to do this reliably and thoroughly.   Nmap is a very powerful tool that can do a whole host of things, and it is worth it to use it for simpler stuff so you can start learning it.

Nmap is free and open source. [Nmap](https://nmap.org/download.html)

It has a GUI, and from the GUI (or the command line too) you can run this command to run a ping scan:

```
nmap -sn -oG Afilewiththepingresults.txt 192.168.1.1-255
```

That gives you everything on the subnet and it writes it to a file.  (It will also show you the results in the GUI too.)

2) There is another "single purpose" scanner that I recommend that has a smaller footprint but it too is open source and free. Pretty slick.  [Angry IP Scanner](http://angryip.org/download/)

3) When I find myself connected to a network wirelessly using my android phone I very happy with [Fing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overlook.android.fing&hl=en) Network Tools.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [10-Strike Network Scanner](http://www.10-strike.com/network-scanner/)
This simple lightweight program will do the job. It works pretty fast and detects IP and MAC addresses both. And it's free.

This is how it looks like

[image]